# XML parser only loading first object

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xcode, xml-parsing

I have a `xml parser` but the function in parser is able to get the first object of the xml file but is not able to get all of the categories of the `xml` file into the `mutable array`. Here is the functions :

```
    let xmlparser = XmlParser()
    xmlparser.loadRssFeed("FaceMask")
    faceMaskArray = (xmlparser.faceMaskArray.firstObject as! FaceMaskCategories).faceMaskItemArray
    collectionArray = faceMaskArray
```

My xml file is as such

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<facemasks>
    <categories>
        <category >
            <id>0</id>
            <title>Animals</title>
            <image_name> leopard</image_name>
            <items>

                <item>
                    <landmarks_file_name>leopard</landmarks_file_name>
                    <item_id>1101</item_id>
                    <mask_title>leopard</mask_title>
                    <mask_image_name>leopard.png</mask_image_name>
                </item>

            </items>
        </category>
        <category >
            <id>1</id>
            <title>Animal</title>
            <image_name>leopard</image_name>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <landmarks_file_name>leopard</landmarks_file_name>
                    <item_id>1102</item_id>
                    <mask_title>leopard</mask_title>
                    <mask_image_name>leopard.png</mask_image_name>
                </item>
            </items>
        </category>
        <category >
            <id>2</id>
            <title>Animals</title>
            <image_name>tiger</image_name>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <landmarks_file_name>leopard</landmarks_file_name>
                    <item_id>1103</item_id>
                    <mask_title>tiger</mask_title>
                    <mask_image_name>tiger.png</mask_image_name>
                </item>
            </items>
        </category>
        <category >
            <id>3</id>
            <title>Animals</title>
            <image_name>tiger</image_name>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <landmarks_file_name>leopard</landmarks_file_name>
                    <item_id>1104</item_id>
                    <mask_title>tigerz</mask_title>
                    <mask_image_name>tiger.png</mask_image_name>
                </item>
            </items>
        </category>
    </categories>
</facemasks>
```

The function is getting only the first object or the last object correctly from the `xml file`. Can anyone please guide me how can I get all of the categories correctly from the xml file. I am really thankful for the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
func beginParsing()
{
posts = []
parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:
(NSURL(string:"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"))!)!
parser.delegate = self
parser.parse()
tbData!.reloadData()
}
```

Here is the parser function with is getting the whole array:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, 
namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes 
attributeDict: [String : String])
{
element = elementName
if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") // Replace this item with category.
{
elements = NSMutableDictionary()
elements = [:]
title1 = NSMutableString()
title1 = ""
date = NSMutableString()
date = ""
}
}
```

It gets all the items from array, "item" is actually tag or each item in array, just like "category" in your sample XML.

This is the sample XML:

http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss#sthash.1Mq673bO.dpuf.

And to parse data from each item:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!)
{
 if element.isEqualToString("title") {
title1.appendString(string)
} else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
date.appendString(string)
}
}
```

I am using this tutorial, it's working fine:

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xml-parsing-using-nsxmlparse-swift